# How to delay jquery events for google analytics

Tags: jquery, delegates, google-analytics

I am using jquery to log clicks on anchors to google analytics.

I have code like the following, that wires up the event:

```
$(document).delegate("a[rel='mylink']", "Click", function (e) {
//log to google analytics
console.log('tracking link');
_gaq.push(event);
e.preventDefault();         
});
```

The problem is that the href seems to be followed too quickly for this event to fire.

Is there a way to delay the following of the href until the event has been fired/completed?

I can see in the console that it gets as far as 'tracking link' but then it moves on before the google analytics push event completes.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: How do you know the analytics event hasn't completed?  In my experience there can be *very* long delays before they show up in the analytics interface.

Comment: I can see in fiddler that the event has not gone across the wire. If I remove the e.preventdefault then I see the event in fiddler but then the href does not load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Analytics records data by making requests for a tracking pixel. As you've found, the request can be canceled when a new page is opened in the same window.

Note: a delay is only necessary if the link being opened in the same window. I use some variation of the following for a click function:

```
function(e) {
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', ...]);
  if (this.target != '_blank') {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = this.href;
    setTimeout(function() {location.href = url}, 150);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problems with google analytics with putting the logic into the window load function

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){


})
```